# Добавить SSL к прокси на nginx = 404?

Tags: nginx, ssl, http-status-code-404

Всем доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся с проблемой настройки `nginx-1.13.8` на `Windows Server`, а именно, когда добавил на `reverse_proxy` SSL сертификат, возникает страница `404`

Конфигурация сейчас (http):

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.3:80;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Конфигурацыя c ssl:

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         ../cert/certcombined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     ../cert/private_rsa.key;


    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.3:80;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Сервер `192.168.0.3` ето апач на линуксе
Извините за возможный `"корявый русский"`

Comment: Не вижу SSL в конфигурации, покажите её

Comment: Добавил конфигурацыю с ssl

Comment: Если так, то не мудрите и объедините обе конфигурации в одну (внутри одного `server` можно прописывать несколько `listen`)

Comment: Зачем вам nginx на windows?

Comment: Но допустим, что надо. Тогда надо смотреть логи сервера

Comment: Я решыл проблему. Никак не пойму как, но когда добавил логи к конфигурации - всё заработало